# While performing clustering with mutualcluster using R I have come across an error

Tags: r, matrix, syntax-error, cluster-analysis, distance

> library(hybridCluster)
> mutual.cluster <-mutualCluster(jarakeuclid, method="average", plot=T)

Output:
Error in if (class(dmat) == "dist") dmat <- as.matrix(dmat) :
the condition has length > 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.